# How to create HTML email template for setup audit trail

Tags: email-template, batchapexerrorevent

I want to implement one functionality where batch class will send the audit trail data in the html body format to the specific recepient. I was trying to create the email template for setup audit trail object but am not getting this kind of object in template but i could query on this object. Anyone help will be appreciated. I have written below apex class and scheduled it but its not getting processed in apex job.it always show in queued status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the method to get the HTML, not the method to send the email. Your scheduler should be:

```
global class auditLogScannerCron1 implements Schedulable {
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    auditLogsScanner1 logScanner = new auditLogsScanner1();
    logScanner.sendEmailMethod();
  }
}
```

By the way, this class only needs to be `public` unless you're using a managed package and want to expose this class to your subscribers.

If your scheduled class isn't executing, make sure you check the NextFireTime field on the job to make sure you haven't accidentally scheduled the job in the past, or for the wrong date/time. I feel like it probably is executing, but you're not getting an email because you called the wrong method; jobs will be repeatedly queued if there are any wild cards in the CRON expression.

Finally, it is **not** an error to iterate over an empty loop. You do not generally need to waste time writing things like `if (!queryResults.isEmpty()) {`.

Comment: I am getting email but showing me an error in job like System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Email body is required.: []. So I have modified  code  still facing same issue. Please find my modified latest code

Comment: I have called getAuditlog method inside the setplaintext body and isaue is resolved mail.setplaintextbody(getAuditlog())

Comment: I am getting email in below text format not in the table format .UserNameSectionActionDetails sid@trailhead.com Apex Class changedApexClass Changed auditLogScannerCron1 Apex Class code sid@trailhead.com Apex Class changedApexClass Changed auditLogsScanner1 Apex Class code. Anyone help will be appreciated

Comment: @SiddharthPotawale Don't strip out the table markup: `messageToSend= htmlBody.stripHtmlTags();` And set the HTML body, not plain text body. You can remove the HTML tags for the plain text version, though.

Comment: I have created custom setting to fetch only the last 1 day data but showing me all the month of data. Please find the latest code. Audit__c is the custom setting.